# Animating part of a view from the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6U5d.png

The above is a relative layout, I want to be able to make it go up using the arrow marker only.

Usually I'd be using a 2d engine to do things like this (coming from making games). I'm not that used to views and such but they seem a little limiting (Like setY doesn't work on some devices..., or placing views off screen resizes them)

Anyhow how would one place this half off screen then allow it to come into view? It's easy to do on iPhone and seems like a hassle on Android (Some tutorials have a gazillion lines of code, I just want something simple..)

Answer (score 0):

Try This my animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:toYDelta="50%p" />
```

Now Give Your Bottom Layout Style:

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Now Give Your Layout Animation by using this:

```
private LinearLayout llShareApp;
llShareApp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llShareApp);
    llShareApp.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.bottom_top));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to do the animation via XML because Android have so many screen sizes. So first, you need to calculate the height of the relative layout part, and the whole screen height, then you can get the actual height you want to lift the part up to the screen and do the animation.

Below is the sample code:

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_order_types"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_mask"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image_all_order"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/all_order" />
    ..............         
    ..............
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Code:

```
// Whole screen height
int heightPixels = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

View layoutOrderTypes = findViewById(R.id.layout_order_types);
layoutOrderTypes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// slide in from bottom animation
Animation inFromBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, 
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, 
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, heightPixels, 
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, (heightPixels - layoutOrderTypes.getHeight() 
                - DisplayUtil.getStatusBarHeight(this)));
inFromBottom.setDuration(300);

// start the animation
layoutOrderTypes.startAnimation(inFromBottom);
```

DisplayUtil.java

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) { 
      int result = 0;
      int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
          result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      } 
      return result;
}
```